# Windows 7 doesn't recognize Nvidia 310m

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

My graphic card (Nvidia Geforce 310M) worked perfectly until today. My laptop restarted unexpectedly, and deleted my drivers. Windows 7 doesn't recognize graphic card in device manager. I tried to reinstall graphic drivers, and same problem. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Were the drivers you installed from the laptop maker?  More detailed info on this may asssit.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> My graphic card (Nvidia Geforce 310M) worked perfectly until today

So, I think it's important to understand what's happen *just before* this problem begin since the driver is no more recognized by Windows (it was before)...

1) The restart was caused by a BSOD I presume... Is it possible to give us the Bug Check error and source? A BSOD create a dump check file. It's possible to easily access this file with the NirSoft utility BlueScreenView  http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

2) In the device management utility `devmgmt.msc` is there an error message for your graphic card (a yellow triangle). What is the error number and description?

3) Did you install another device driver or another driver just before this problem? The NirSoft's *Serviwin* may help you to check all drivers are installed and started in your system: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/serviwin.html

4) have you tried to do a restore to an earlier date?

As far as I know the source of this problem may be:

- A wrong (corrupted, obsolete, incompatible) version of your graphic
  card driver
- Another driver incompatible to the graphic driver (including a
  malware!)
- An hardware problem with the graphic card

*What you can try:* Double check the driver version from the manufacturer web site, download it and install it in safe mode with a minimum of external devices connected.

*If* the problem can't be reproduced, this may be another driver loaded in "normal boot"...

*If* the problem is still present in safe mode *may be* it's hardware (say at "75%") ...

Hope this help. Let us know.